# Why Angular Two-Way Binding doesn't work with parameter passed through routerLink?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am passing the **object** through `routerLink` and updating the form input based on object properties. But when I change the content of the form input, the object properties don't update.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="center.id">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="center.name" placeholder="name">

<tr *ngFor="let center of centers">
  <td [routerLink]="['/add-center', center]">{{center.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

In the component:

```
center: Center;

constructor(private centerService: CenterService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

}
```

Getting the parameter from the `routerLink`:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.route.params.subscribe(center => {
    this.center = center;
  });
}
```

After submitting the form, I call the following method:

```
editCenter() {

  this.centerService.updateCenter(this.center)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log('Updated Successfully');
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  ;
  console.log(this.center);
}
```

The method prints the same properties for the object in the log. It doesn't update the properties of the object.

Tried to manually change the properties but got the following error:

> TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.

Comment: If the code from the first code snipper is all in the same template, try changing the name of center variable, since it's the same as center in ngFor.

Comment: I tried but didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us your Center class/interface?

Comment: is this a form? I see no form tags?

Comment: @Alex It is a form and it has form tags.

Answer (score 1):

Since we found out that this is indeed a form (with form tag)... As your code sits now, you should get an error in your console, since you haven't provided a `name` attribute for your fields. This you need to do if you are having a form.

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="center.id" name="id">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="center.name" placeholder="name" name="name">
</form>
```

Having the `name` attribute should update your model fine.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-44su8u?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: I added the name attributes but still the same problem. I am passing the object through `routherLink` parameter. Does this make it read-only?

Comment: Ah see, I was carelessly reading. You can't pass an object like that as a parameter. You might want to consider a service: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service Don't mind the title, it works with non-related components, you just need to change the `Subject`-type. Use a `BehaviorSubject` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`this.centerService.updateCenter(this.center)` is asynchronous. You will need to put your console inside the `subscribe` callback to see the changes.

```
editCenter() {
    this.centerService.updateCenter(this.center)
        .subscribe(
            res => {
                console.log('Updated Successfully');
                console.log(this.center);
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
}
```

Comment: The two-way data binding is not working. For instance, if I am changing content `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="center.name" placeholder="name">` input, it should update the `name` property of the object (center), but it does not.